# Different proof of MVT?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am going to make a seemingly very obvious question but it's something that I can't answer even when trying to find some extra resources on google! Is it possible to prove the Mean Value Theorem without using Rolle's theorem? Is there another way to prove that theorem that is more intuitive?

Comment: Don't you think that Rolle's theorem is quite intuitive, though?

Comment: @littleO Setting without any clue a function and applying Rolle's Theorem to it is something that seems to me non-intuitive. That's why I want a more direct proof if possible!

Comment: I also used to find that to be uninutuitive, but I guess I got used to it. There is a joke that to prove the MVT all you need to do is tilt your head to the side and apply Rolle's theorem. This joke might suggest modifying $f$ in a very minimal way to obtain a function for which Rolle's theorem applies. And the simplest way to modify $f$ so that Rolle's theorem will apply is to subtract a linear function from $f$. Once we have that idea, completing the proof of MVT is easy.

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis do you want an intuitive explanation for why MVT works? That I can provide. But as of a proof that doesn't require Rolle's theorem, well, since they essentially reduce to each other, I don't know if there is one.

Comment: @littleO My other problem on this topic is that I don't want to see MVT as a geometrical property of a function and see it completely algebraicaly! Yeah, I know that there is no need on trying to make such a topic harder and harder but I always try to find other ways to see math instead of those provided by books!

Comment: After all I want to make a last question! Is the initial proof of MVT that one that we see in all books or the mathematician that discovered it had another proof of that?